# Sign of Rational Exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given $x<0$.

$$\sqrt{x^2} . \frac{-1}{x}$$

why does this give:

$$\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2}}$$

instead of:

$$-\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2}}$$

I can see how plugging in $-1$ exposes the error but I would like to know the general rule that can applied.

Comment: second fraction is 1 and first seems like -1? i guess, what is wrong with that

Comment: Who says it does or doesn't give that? The value depends on whether $x>0$, and how one defines $\sqrt{y}$.

Comment: But then, what happens when $x=-1,$ @Nehorai?

Comment: basically, you have not given us enough context. "It" gives one or the other, depending on $x$.

Comment: But neither is true for all $x$, which is my point. @Nehorai

Comment: sorry people.... edited

Comment: you don't have to put $ x \to -\infty$, just put $x <0$

Comment: you can't get something negative that is outside the square root inside!!! By doing that you are disrupting the equality, because you are changing the sign and hence is not a correct simplification.

Comment: @LuisVera relax yourself

Comment: @EricJohnson sorry if I was too emphatic, just trying to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition: 
$$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|=\bigg\{\begin{array}{r}
                       x, \ \ x\geq 0 \\
                       -x, \ \ x<0
                       \end{array}$$
so relation
$$\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{\sqrt{x^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{|x|}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2}}{-x}=\sqrt{x^2} . \frac{-1}{x}$$
is true if $x$ is negative.

Comment: You should make clear which you mean by "your relation." OP is objecting to the first expression and proposing the second as an alternative. The first is valid for $x<0$, but the second is more likely to be referenced as "your expression."

Comment: @ Thomas Andrews: thanks! I hope its better stated now.

Answer (score 0):

This is because:

$x ≠ \sqrt{x^2}$ for all negative $x$.

$x = -\sqrt{x^2}$ if $x < 0$